# What is the correct solution of $\sqrt[7]{(-\sqrt{3}-i)^5}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

$\sqrt[7]{(-\sqrt{3}-i)^5}=(-\sqrt{3}-i)^\frac{5}{7}=
2^\frac{5}{7}(\cos(\frac{5}{7}\alpha)+i\sin(\frac{5}{7}\alpha)=$

$\tan\alpha=\frac{-1}{-\sqrt{3}} \implies \alpha=\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi$

$=2^\frac{5}{7}(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{42}+\frac{2k\pi}{7})+i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{42}+\frac{2k\pi}{7})$

The problem I have currently is that I have no idea where I made an error. 
 The correct solution is 
$2^\frac{5}{7}(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6}+\frac{2k\pi}{7})+i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6}+\frac{2k\pi}{7})$.

Comment: The complex number $-\sqrt{3}-i$ is in the **third** quadrant, so $\alpha=\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{7\pi}{6}$. When you took $\tan \alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ you lost the fact that both $\sin$ and $\cos$ are negative.

Comment: I see  a problem in the first implication: $\;\tan \alpha=\frac 1{\sqrt 3}\implies \alpha=\frac\pi 6+k\pi$.

Comment: @AnuragA Didn't even thought about 3rd quadrant! Makes total sense!

Answer (score 1):

$(-\sqrt3-i)^5$ is a *specific* complex number, but it can be written in multiple ways, making use of the fact that $e^{i2\pi k}=1$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$: Since

$$-\sqrt3-i=-2\left(\sqrt3+i\over2\right)=-2\left(\cos\left(\pi\over6\right)+i\sin\left(\pi\over6\right)\right)=-2e^{i\pi/6}$$

we have

$$(-\sqrt3-i)^5=-2^5e^{i5\pi/6}=2^5e^{i11\pi/6}=2^5e^{i23\pi/6}=2^5e^{i35\pi/6}=2^5e^{i47\pi/6}=\cdots$$

Now among the numbers $11$, $23$, $35$, $47$, etc., we see one that's nicely divisible by $7$, so writing

$$(-\sqrt3-i)^5=2^5e^{i(35\pi/6+2\pi k)}$$

we get

$$\sqrt[7]{(-\sqrt3-i)^5}=2^{5/7}e^{i({5\pi/6}+2\pi k/7)}=2^{5/7}\left(\cos\left({5\pi\over6}+{2\pi k\over7}\right)+i\sin\left({5\pi\over6}+{2\pi k\over7}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the set of solutions to the equation
$$
x^7 = (-\sqrt3 -i)^5.
$$
Now, taking the polar form of $-\sqrt3 -i$ you get
$$
(-\sqrt3 -i)^5 = \left(2\, e^{-5\pi/6}\right)^5 
= 2^5 e^{-25\pi/6}
= 2^5 e^{-\pi/6}
$$
therefore the solutions are 
$$
\{
2^{5/7} e^{-\pi/6 + 2 k \pi/7}, k=0,1,...,6
\}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You just divided twice by $7$.

$$\sqrt[7]{(-\sqrt3-i)^5}=\sqrt[7]{32\left(\cos(5\cdot210^{\circ})+i\sin(5\cdot210^{\circ})\right)}=$$
$$=2^{\frac{5}{7}}\left(\cos\left(150^{\circ}+\frac{360^{\circ}k}{7}\right)+i\sin\left(150^{\circ}+\frac{360^{\circ}k}{7}\right)\right),$$ where $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.